# godaddy dns + aliyun host - django app, uwsgi, nginx - shows "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: nginx, django, godaddy, uwsgi

I have domain mydomain.me in godaddy 
i set it to point to my ip in aliyun ecs

In my diango settings i have :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".mydomain.me","x.x.x.x"]
```

in /etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/Django i have

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}

server {
    listen x.x.x.x:80;
    server_name .mydomain.me;
    location /static/ {
                include uwsgi_params;
                alias /root/DjangoApps/mydomain_me/public;
    }

    location /  {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass django;

    }
}
```

**edit : ** for which I made symlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/Django, and removed default symlink.

In uwsgi.ini i have

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/DjangoApps/mydomain_me
module = mydomain_me.wsgi:application
processes = 1
threads = 1
stats = 127.0.0.1:9000
daemonize = /tmp/daemon_app
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid
chmod-socket = 777
master = True
vaccum = True
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

i run this as follows with pycharm:

```
ssh://root@x.x.x.x:22/opt/miniconda3/envs/DjangoApps/bin/python3.6 -u /root/DjangoApps/mydomain_me/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 
ssh://root@x.x.x.x:22:bash 

root@mydomain:~/DjangoApps/mydomain_me# . activate DjangoApps 
(DjangoApps) root@mydomain:~/DjangoApps/mydomain_me# uwsgi uwsgi.ini 
(DjangoApps) root@mydomain:~/DjangoApps/mydomain_me# service nginx restart
```

this is ok:

```
http://mydomain.me:8080
```

It worked!

> Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
>
> Next, start your first app by running python manage.py startapp
>   [app_label].
>
> You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your
>   Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!

but rhis is not:

```
http://mydomain.me
```

with output:

> Welcome to nginx!

why its not working?

**edit**

now mydomain.me gives output:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>
> nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

And this are my authorization rules:

outbound:

```
Allow   
Custom TCP  
8080/8080 and 80/80 and 22/22 and 3389/3389
Address Field Access    
0.0.0.0/0
```

inbound:

```
none
```

Should I change anything? Also my domain point to internet IP address, not elastic one.

**edit 1**:
cat /var/log/nginx/error.log gives me output:

```
> 2017/08/13 03:00:34 [error] 19132#19132: *11 connect() to
> unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting
> to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: mydomain.me, request:
> "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "mydomain.me", referrer:
> "http://mydomain.me/"
```

And the file /tmp/uwsgi.sock exists, but when:

```
cat /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

it says:

```
> cat: /tmp/uwsgi.sock: No such device or address
```

Comment: Did you reload nginx after adding the configuration?

Comment: Always: service nginx restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after

```
cat /tmp/daemon_app
```

problem was here:

> probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address
>   (127.0.0.1:9000).

Solution is to kill process using port 9000 and run uwsgi again...

```
sudo fuser -k 9000/tcp && uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```

Though, I dont know the reason... Any hints would be nice. I just opened this server yesterday, besides I'm noob in networking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Nginx config isn't linked/included.  If it's in a directory named `sites-available`, you'll need to symlink to it from `sites-enabled`.  Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and check which directories it loads config files from.

Example for symlinking a config named `default.conf`:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/default.conf
sudo service nginx restart
```